# If $f:2^{\omega}\longrightarrow 2^{\omega}$ is a homeomorphism and $J\subseteq 2^{\omega}$ is a maximal ideal, then $f[J]$ is a maximal ideal?

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Working on a problem about restrictions of homeomorphisms to maximal ideals of the set of Cantor $2^{\omega}$ I came up with the following question:

**If $f:2^{\omega}\longrightarrow 2^{\omega}$ is a homeomorphism and $J\subseteq 2^{\omega}$ is a maximal ideal, then $f[J]$ is a maximal ideal?**

Comment: Why should it even be an ideal again?

Comment: I guess "ideal" has to do with the identification of $2^\omega$ with the power set of $\omega$.  If so, consider this homeomorphism: map each set to its complement.  This will map maximal ideals to maximal filters.